# AngularJS using Filter inside a Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, ngTableParams, $filter){
    $http.get('/assets/inc/data').success(function(response) {
        $scope.items = response;
        $filter('offset', function() {
        return function(input, start) {
            console.log(start);
            start = parseInt(start, 10);
            return input.slice(start);
        };
    });
    });
}]);
```

I have a small applications that I am trying to use `$filter` in. The filter needs to be available when `$http.get` has finished running but the above doesn't work.

Where have I went wrong?

Comment: $filter('filtername')(arg1,arg2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sort of mixing things up. The filter itself has to be created as *app.filter()* and afterwards applied as sylwester mentioned.

Create:

```
app.filter('filterName' , function() {
    return function(arg1, arg2, ..., argN) {
        // what ever it does
        return ...;
    };
});
```

Apply:

```
$filter('filterName') (arg1, arg2, ..., argN);
```

See: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XUgqVF3zDzGLyjLhZ0JQ?p=preview)